# Borrowing on RefCell

Tags: rust

I'm just getting started with rust, and trying to implement some simple data structures. I am getting the following error on an iterator for a doubly linked list, and cannot understand why this is happening.

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

struct Node<T> {
    value: T,
    next: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>,
    prev: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>,
}

impl<T> Node<T> {
    fn new(value: T) -> Rc<RefCell<Self>> {
        Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node {
            value,
            next: None,
            prev: None,
        }))
    }
}

pub struct DoublyLinkedList<T> {
    head: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>,
    tail: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>,
    len: usize,
}

impl<T> DoublyLinkedList<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        DoublyLinkedList {
            head: None,
            tail: None,
            len: 0,
        }
    }

    pub fn len(&self) -> usize {
        self.len
    }

    pub fn is_empty(&self) -> bool {
        self.len == 0
    }

    pub fn push_front(&mut self, value: T) {
        let new_node = Node::new(value);
        match self.head.take() {
            Some(old_head) => {
                old_head.borrow_mut().prev = Some(new_node.clone());
                new_node.borrow_mut().next = Some(old_head);
                self.head = Some(new_node);
            }
            None => {
                self.head = Some(new_node.clone());
                self.tail = Some(new_node);
            }
        }
        self.len += 1;
    }

    pub fn push_back(&mut self, value: T) {
        let new_node = Node::new(value);
        match self.tail.take() {
            Some(old_tail) => {
                old_tail.borrow_mut().next = Some(new_node.clone());
                new_node.borrow_mut().prev = Some(old_tail);
                self.tail = Some(new_node);
            }
            None => {
                self.head = Some(new_node.clone());
                self.tail = Some(new_node);
            }
        }
        self.len += 1;
    }

    pub fn pop_front(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        self.head.take().map(|old_head| {
            match old_head.borrow_mut().next.take() {
                Some(new_head) => {
                    new_head.borrow_mut().prev = None;
                    self.head = Some(new_head);
                }
                None => {
                    self.tail = None;
                }
            }
            self.len -= 1;
            Rc::try_unwrap(old_head).ok().unwrap().into_inner().value
        })
    }

    pub fn pop_back(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        self.tail.take().map(|old_tail| {
            match old_tail.borrow_mut().prev.take() {
                Some(new_tail) => {
                    new_tail.borrow_mut().next = None;
                    self.tail = Some(new_tail);
                }
                None => {
                    self.head = None;
                }
            }
            self.len -= 1;
            Rc::try_unwrap(old_tail).ok().unwrap().into_inner().value
        })
    }

    pub fn iter(&self) -> Iter<T> {
        Iter {
            next: self.head.as_ref().map(|node| node.clone()),
        }
    }
}

pub struct Iter<T> {
    next: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>,
}

impl<T> Iterator for Iter<T> {
    type Item = T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.next.take().map(|node| {
            self.next = node
                .borrow()
                .next
                .as_ref()
                .map(|next_node| next_node.clone());
            node.borrow().value
            // Rc::try_unwrap(node).ok().unwrap().into_inner().value
        })
    }
}
```

I would have thought the borrow would be able to pull the internal value of the RefCell, but I'm getting the following error:

```
cannot move out of dereference of `Ref<'_, Node<T>>`

node.borrow().value
move occurs because value has type `T`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

However, the commented out code below it works.

Comment: Not an answer, but a popular link on topic, which is advised to follow if doing something like this anyway: https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/

Comment: can you share `Node` struct as well so we can test the code

Comment: Should probably be `type Item = &'a T;` with `Iter<T>` being changed to `Iter<'a, T>` and then `next()` can return a reference.

Comment: @Yilmaz I've updated it to show all of the code.

Comment: @cdhowie I've gone down that path as well, getting a different error, but still not working. I would've posted the full code, but I don't think it will fit here.

Comment: @Cerberus I've actually gone through half of that before starting on my own, that has helped me to understand a lot, which is why im baffled by this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RefCell::borrow()` returns a `Ref<Node>` which implements `Deref<Target = Node>`, which gives you an `&Node` reference, which lets you read from it but not mutate it *or move it out*.

The line `node.borrow().value` is attempting to move out the contents of the field `value` of the `Node` structure. You cannot do that given only the `&Node` access.

As a general principle in Rust:

- If you have `&T` you can read from the `T`. **This is the situation you are in.**
- If you have `&mut T` then you can read and also mutate the `T`; and you can move out the `T` but only if you swap in a replacement (with `std::mem::swap` or one of its relatives).
- If you have `T` then you can do everything that `&mut T` allows and also move out *without* replacing.

In order to move the value out of a `RefCell`, without a replacement, your

```rust
Rc::try_unwrap(node).ok().unwrap().into_inner().value
```

is the right way to go about it; deconstructing the wrappers until you have the value. Many Rust types will have methods in the style of `into_inner()`, precisely so that this sort of thing is possible.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, what I'm not clear on is then this would only work for the case where there is a value, but would panic otherwise. I know, because I've written a simple test that causes this when the value is 'None'. So how would I go about doing this in a manner that would not cause a panic, and is basically not assuming the 'ok()'.

Also, I'm confused here because if I'm calling "borrow()", why does that "move" the value ? I thought "borrow" was a non mut reference which could be passed and didnt cause a "move". Otherwise, the name of "borrow" is very misleading.

Comment: @John Ah, I see what I didn't explain; edited. `borrow()` is not responsible for the move; `.value` is. `borrow()` returns `Ref<Node>` which acts like `&Node`, but `.value` wants to move out, and you can't move out of an `&Node`.

Comment: @John Oh, I see the real problem. I thought your iterator was intending to consume the list (return the values and destroy the nodes). If you want to iterate over the list without destroying it, you will need to change the iterator to either return `Ref<T>`s, not `T`s, or to `clone` each item of the list.

Comment: thanks, im gonna have to process that, because this whole time I've been learning, i thought 'borrow' was the actually 'borrow'. You've just flipped everything i thought i knew on its head :).

Comment: @John Borrowing is borrowing, but a move cannot be done through a borrow, and you were attempting a move.